# Difference between two Lists with non-unique Entries

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists stings. One represents types of functions that my code can run, and another agents that would run the functions. Those two lists should stand in a 1 to 1 relation, but when a remote service requests more functions I need to find out the difference between those two lists.
The problem is that the entries are non-unique, so I can't just call `list1.RemoveAll(list2)` as this would remove all entries with the same value contained in List2 instead of just one per entry.

This is what I need:

```
{a,a,a,a,b,b,c} - {a,a,b,c} = {a,a,b}
```

This is how I do it right now:

```
var difference = list1.ToList();
foreach (var entry in list2)
{
    difference.Remove(entry);
}
```

It's functional and does the job, but it breaks the Linq usage I have through the rest of the code.

I tried to figure out a way and searched online, but couldn't find a way to do this using Linq.

Comment: The way you have is simple and good. Why change it into Linq? EDIT: Removed last part of comment.

Comment: Because right now it's a comparable big blob of code in an else Linq only code, making it a harder to read. I also could make a method into a single return call with this as Linq instead of the current two.

Comment: Does the order of the lists ever matter (or, is it always sorted alphabetically)? Can it ever occur that something in `list2` does not exist (in the same multiplicity) in `list1`, i.e. that the `Remove` call in the loop will return `false` and not remove anything? It look like what you have might be modelled as _multisets_ with the natural "set difference" of multisets.

Comment: Due to the nature of the code list2 is guaranteed to be smaller than list1. list2 gets build up from 0 to satisfy list1.

Comment: are the lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @Magnus No, they should be, but it's not something guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

In case of *long* collections (sequencies) where nested loops and `Remove` can be ineffective (from `O (N * M)` to `O(N * N * M)`) you can try `grouping` and `dictionary` with `O (N + M)` time complexity. Please notice that the implementation *doesn't keep* the *initial order* (`{a, b, b, a} - {b} == {a, a, b}`, not `{a, b, a}`):

```
List<char> left = new List<char>() { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c' };
List<char> right = new List<char>() { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c' };

var counts = right
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Count());

var difference = left
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .SelectMany(chunk => chunk.Skip(counts.TryGetValue(chunk.Key, out var skip) ? skip : 0))
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** It's easy to create a *benchmark*; and in case of long sequences (`N = 200000`) *hash* (`GroupBy`, `Dictionary`) prevails; sure if you *don't have* that long collections you can safely keep the initial code:

```
Random rnd = new Random(1);

int N = 200000;

List<char> left = Enumerable
  .Range(0, N)
  .Select(index => (char)(rnd.Next('z' - 'a') + 'a'))
  .ToList();

List<char> right = Enumerable
  .Range(0, N)
  .Select(index => (char)(rnd.Next('z' - 'a') + 'a'))
  .ToList();
```

Now let horses run:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();

// Hash solution
var counts = right
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Count());

var result = left
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .SelectMany(chunk => chunk.Skip(counts.TryGetValue(chunk.Key, out var skip) ? skip : 0))
  .ToList();

watch.Stop();

TimeSpan tHash = watch.Elapsed;

watch.Reset();
watch.Start();

// Initial solution
var difference = left.ToList();

foreach (var entry in right) {
  difference.Remove(entry);
}

watch.Stop();

TimeSpan tInitial = watch.Elapsed;

Console.Write($"Hash: {tHash}; Initial {tInitial}");
```

Outcome (Core i7 3.6GHz) `11 ms` vs. `1.4 second`

```
  Hash: 00:00:00.0111296; Initial 00:00:01.3957468
```

Comment: This solves the problem with Linq, but I doubt it's more performant than my current one, as you go through the lists several more times than my code. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: @Gregor A. Lamche: if lists are short then you are quite right (they are not worth hash optimization); however, in case of *long* lists *hashing* will do a better job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your code does what you want:

```
var list1 = {b, b, c, a};
var list2 = {a, b, b, c};
```

Your code will remove all elements, even though the order in the second list differs from the order in your first list.

```
var list1 = {a, b, a, c, a};
var list2 = {a, a, b, c};
var list3 = {b, c, a, a}
```

list1 - list2 and list1 - list3 will have the same output:

```
result = {b, c, a}
```

Is this what you want? Is the order important?

Besides your code changes the input data. LINQ is meant to query data, no LINQ function ever changes the input data. If you really want your code to change the input data, it cannot be converted to a LINQ like function.

However, if you don't want to change the input sequences, we can "extend" the functionality of `IEnumerable`with a new function that does your functionality as if it was a LINQ function, with the exception that it does not change the input sequences.

The function will have two `IEnumerable<TSource>` as inputs, and it returns one `IEnumerable<TSource>` as output. The input sequences are not changed.

See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> RemoveDuplicates<TSource> (
        this IEnumerable<Tsource> list1,
        IEnumerable<TSource> list2)
    {
         // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

(I couldn't think of a proper name)

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<string> list1 = ...
IEnumerable<string> list2 = ...

IEnumerable<string> result = list1.RemoveDuplicates(list2);
```

Or in an intricate LINQ function:

```
var result = list1.Where(x => x.StartsWith("a")
   .RemoveDuplicates(list2.Where(x => x.EndsWith("z")
   .Select(x => ...)
   .ToList();
```

If this is what you want, let's implement it.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> RemoveDuplicates<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<Tsource> list1,
    IEnumerable<TSource> list2)
{
    var differenct = list1.ToList();
    foreach (var entry in list2)
    {
        difference.Remove(entry);
    }
    return difference;
}
```

This is not very efficient. For instance if you only want to `Any()` or `FirstOrDefault()` with the result it is not efficient to calculate the complete list.

If the order of your result is not important, you could group the input by same string and return only the difference in number of elements. So if list1 has 5 "a" and list2 has 3 "a", you return 2 times an "a". For this you can groupBy the string, and count the number of items in each group.

For simplicity, my comments are as if we remove several "a" values from your input

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> RemoveDuplicates<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<Tsource> list1,
    IEnumerable<TSource> list2)
{
    var group1 = list1.GroupBy(item => item)
       .Select(group => new
       {
           value = group.Key,
           count = group.Count(),
       });

    var group2 = list2.GroupBy(item => item)
       .Select(group => new
       .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

    // for every item in group1, check if there is a same one in group2.
    // If so, subtract the count and return the remaining items
    foreach (var item in group1)
    {
        // are the also some "a" values in list2?
        if (group2.TryGetValue(item1.Value, out int nrToremove))
        {
            // yes there are: nrToRemove contains the number of "a" values in list2
            int nrToReturn = item.Count - nrToRemove;

            // return all remaining "a" values:
            for (int i=0; i<nrToReturn; ++i)
            {
                yield return item.Value;  // return an "a"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because of the yield, statement, this function uses deferred execution. Only if you start enumerating your LINQ, it will be executed.

Because the "a" to remove could be the last one in list2, to get your first returned element we'll have to enumerate all elements of list2 to check if the first "a" is anywhere in list2. Because I remember the results of this enumeration, list2 doesn't have to be enumerated again to return the 2nd (and any other) element.